# Rails ajax call returns 500

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have got a ajax call which deletes some data from database. The data is deleted properly, but The action returns a failure ...

code looks like this:

```
def remove_user_from_group
  @usergroup = UserGroup.find params[:usergroup_id]
  @user = User.find params[:user_id]
  @usergroup.users.delete(@user)
  if @usergroup.save
    flash[:notice] = t("flash.deleted")
    render :add_user_to_group
  else
    flash[:notice] = t("flash.login_failed_nouser")
    render :add_user_to_group
  end
end
```

Whats going wrong?  I do exactly the same for adding data and it works fine.

Comment: To start with, you could look at your server logs. I'm guessing you are using a variable in your `:add_user_to_group` template that is not declared in your `remove_user_from_group` action...

Comment: yep that was the hint I needed thanks :) I missed to set the @users variable